# How would I about calculating the average RTT over n trials between me and the server?

Tags: c, http, sockets

I have my code that calculates the RTT between the client and the server but I am having trouble figuring out how to implement a for loop to find the average RTT given 10 trials. Any advice?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define RCVBUFSIZE 32

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);
int getAddressInfo(const char* host, unsigned short* port, struct sockaddr_in* sock_addr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in httpServAddr;
    unsigned short httpServPort;
    char *httpRequest = "GET/ HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                        "Host: %s\r\n"
                        "Connection: close\r\n\r\n";
    char httpBuffer[RCVBUFSIZE];
    int bytesRcvd, totalBytesRcvd;

    if (argc < 2 || argc > 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Server IP/URL> [<HTTP Port>]\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    const char* host = argv[1];

    memset(&httpServAddr, 0, sizeof(httpServAddr));
    if (getAddressInfo(host, &httpServPort, &httpServAddr) != 0) {
        DieWithError("Failed to get server address information");
    }

    if (argc == 3) {
        httpServPort = atoi(argv[2]);
    } else {
        httpServPort = 80;
    }

    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
        DieWithError("socket() failed");
    }


    httpServAddr.sin_port = htons(httpServPort);

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &httpServAddr, sizeof(httpServAddr)) < 0) {
        DieWithError("connect() failed");
    }

    char request[strlen(httpRequest) + strlen(host) + 1];
    sprintf(request, httpRequest, host);

    if (send(sock, request, strlen(request), 0) != strlen(request)) {
        DieWithError("send() sent a different number of bytes than expected");
    }

    totalBytesRcvd = 0;
    printf("Received: ");

    struct timeval start, end;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    while ((bytesRcvd = recv(sock, httpBuffer, RCVBUFSIZE - 1, 0)) > 0) {
        totalBytesRcvd += bytesRcvd;
        httpBuffer[bytesRcvd] = '\0';
        printf("%s", httpBuffer);
    }

    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    long rtt = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000 + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000;

    if (bytesRcvd < 0) {
        DieWithError("recv() failed");
    }

    printf("\n\nRound-trip time: %ld ms\n", rtt);

    close(sock);
    exit(0);
}

int getAddressInfo(const char* host, unsigned short* port, struct sockaddr_in* httpServAddr) {
    struct addrinfo hints = {0};
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    struct addrinfo* result;
    int ret = getaddrinfo(host, NULL, &hints, &result);
    if (ret != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo() failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret));
        return -1;
    }
    // Copy the server address information to the httpServAddr struct
    memcpy(httpServAddr, (struct sockaddr_in*)result->ai_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    *port = ntohs(httpServAddr->sin_port);

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    return 0;
}

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage) {
    perror(errorMessage);
    exit(1);
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out where which part of the code I should wrap in for a loop. It seems hard to get the code to find the RTT multiple times after it has found it once. This code can be tested by putting a URL and socket number into the terminal. For example:  ./client [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)  80

Comment: _Side note:_ Instead of `gettimeofday`, I'd use `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...);`

Answer (score 0):

In your header, you put Connection: close, so this answer will consider that you want to connect to the server again on each iteration of the loop.

You would want to wrap the part of the code that you are connecting, sending, and receiving data. In the loop, and add the times to an array, and calculate the average time of the array.

Quick side note, I would not recommend using variable length arrays, as you did for the request buffer. Although they are supported in C99, they generally aren't a good practice.

I would try something like this:

```c
int main()
{

    // ommitted creating socket for simplicity 

    long rtts[10] = { 0 };
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
         connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &httpServAddr,sizeof(httpServAddr));
         struct timeval start, end;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

         // send and receive omitted for simplicity

         gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
         rtts[i] = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000 + (end.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000;
         close(sock);
    }

   // after for loop of requests are complete 
   long sum = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
         sum+=rtts[i];
   }

   long avg = sum / 10;

   return 0;
}
```